# Polymer on Cordova built iOS and Android apps

Tags: polymer

Is Polymer compatible with the iOS Safari and Chrome Browsers, and the web view that Cordova uses?

As I think to build an HTML5 mobile app with Cordova, I am in look for a gui framework. Polymer seems powerful. I am just in doubt that it works in iOS since there are some github issues and SO questions about that.

Does Polymer works in Cordova built mobile apps for iOS and Android without issues?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on an app that is built entirely on polymer. I don't use any of the common elements. All elements are custom and built by our team. At first there were some gotchas but it works great on iOS8+.

Comment: Hey we have a web app completely made by Polymer too and now starting to try to convert it to iOS. Any guide or start point that you could direct us to would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about iOS, but I can say it works well in Android using Cordova.

I've used Polymer components in [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) apps, that uses Cordova to generate the mobile apps. I'm not an iOS developer, so I've only generated Android apps, and they worked well in all the devices where I tested it (mostly Android 4.2+).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use Cordova with Polymer, but when the device isn't an Android you need load the WebComponents-Lite.

If you want, I have a seed that should help you, it's an Cordova-Angular-Polymer Seed (but it isn't an Ionic Framework Seed):

https://github.com/mario-aleo/cordova-angular-polymer-seed